# How to cross-redo in Vim, i.e. redo the changes after made some edit after an undo?

Tags: vim, vi

In vim, How to redo the changes after I made some edit after an undo?

For example, I typed `asdf` and `!`, got `asdf!`. Then I performed an undo and typed `?` got `asdf?`.

Is there a way to get the `asdf!` state using undo/redo?

Comment: `:earlier` does what you want. See `:help undo-tree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:earlier` does what you want. See `:help undo-tree`.